# Navigate to custompage with Freshmvvm

Tags: xamarin.forms, freshmvvm

Im implementing Facebook login in an app, where I'm using FreshMvvm. The login is implemented using a PageRenderer in each platform combined with Xamarin.Auth component. The issue is how I shold navigate to to this new page. Previously using MvvmHelpers, I did a PushAsync. Doing the same with FreshMvvm where I also made an empty PageModel, I get a LoginPagePage as the result, which was not what it should be. So my question is, how should I navigate to my CustomPage? Can it be done with CoreMethods.xxxx?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Solved by encapsulating the page inside its own navigationservice and replacing it when needed.